# Is it possible to upload a server file to cloud using multer?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multer-s3

I want to upload a file which is being generated on my server conditionally in a directory, and I am using multer-s3 package to upload files to S3 service.

Is it possible to upload that generated file from server directory to S3 using multer-s3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to upload the generated file to `s3` using `multer-s3`, because `multer-s3` library has been designed and written in a way to provide alternative storage engine to `multer`, not as a library to upload file to `s3`. You can use some other library to upload files to `s3` or you can read it here https://github.com/badunk/multer-s3/blob/master/index.js#L172